# How do I use Path.home()?

Tags: python, path, python-3.7

I'm new to Python and I just can't figure out why

`from pathlib import Path
..
..
..
sys.stdout = open('Path.home()' + '\\Desktop\\Report.txt','a')`

doesn't work. It says there is no such path.

I just want the snippet to get the active user desktop path and place that txt there; Python 3.7.

If anybody could help, I would be grateful.

Comment: You should always include code that can be run, so people can actually test it. I can't reproduce your problem on my system. I'm assuming that Path.home() + '\Desktop\Report.txt' simply doesn't exist. Have you checked that it is trying to retrieve from the correct location?

Comment: Yes, sorry: this is the full code:

Comment: Damn I can't include all of it, but it's basically sys.stdout = open('Path.home()' + '\\Desktop\\Report.txt','a')
    #some more stuff
   
    print('-'*105)
    
    sys.stdout.close()

Answer (score 0):

Also tried like this, it doesn't want to change the path from C:\Desktop

```
checkuser = getpass.getuser()
sys.stdout = open(Path.home() / 'Users' / checkuser / '\\Desktop\\Report.txt','a')
```

Comment: *also with str(checkuser)

Answer (score 0):

This worked just fine on my Mac:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
home_path = str(Path.home())
print (open((home_path + '/Desktop/Report.txt'), 'a'))
```

Comment: On Windows, it prints the output to console; it creates the txt, but it is empty. What I did instead was home_path = str(Path.home())
sys.stdout = open(home_path + '\\Desktop\\Report.txt','a') , this way, it works. Thanks !